# Blender outliner Context Menu entry

Tags: python, interface, panel

[image]

I want to add an entry in the object context menu of the outliner. I tried with  `bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_context_menu` with no results.

Any idea how i can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i found the answer and it was dead simple :

```
bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_object.append(menu_func)
```

Comment: You should note that the menu is different if you click on a collection, in a blank space, on a button or on an object in the outliner